# How are the alpha vacua, the Bunch Davies vacuum and Adiabatic vacuum different in context of inflationary cosmology?

Tags: space-expansion, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

I do understand that the Bunch-Davies is the most standard vacuum to consider as an initial condition, but what if there are deviations from a de Sitter spacetime that do not generically reduce the inflaton field to a Bunch-Davies vacuum at a large negative conformal time? Also then, which one of the three (alpha vacuum, Bunch-Davies, Adiabatic vacuum) should be used to find a primordial power spectrum for getting theoretical $C_\ell$'s for the CMB?